# How to calculate the coefficient of the model MA (1), with negative discriminant

Tags: arima, autocorrelation

In the calculation of the coefficient of the model MA(1) the following formula is used.[image]
For example, if the first value of acf=0.1923, the discriminant is D=B^2-4*A*C.
D=0.85208
The solution has two roots.
x1=0.2
x2=5

Now take a value of acf=-0.77.
D=-1.3716. I read that if the discriminant is negative, then the solution has no roots.
How to obtain coefficients for MA(1) model with negative discriminant?

P.S. And if the discriminant is negative, then the process is not stationary? And so the data must be subjected to another difference to remove the trend.
Please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theoretical autocorrelation at lag 1 is bounded between $-0.5$ and $0.5$ for the MA(1) model, but the corresponding sample autocorrelation is not.  Hence, when you equate these quantities (to obtain the [method-of-moment estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics))), you may end up with an equation with no real solution for $\theta$ (a negative discriminant) and no method-of-moment estimate.